# Quasi Injective vs Pseudo Injective modules

Tags: ring-theory

$\textbf{Definition:}$ A left $R$ module $M$ is called QI (PI) - module if for every submodule $N$, any $R$-homomomorphism (monomorphism) $N\rightarrow M$ extends to an endomorphism of $M$.

For QI - modules we have the following theorem:

$\textbf{Theorem}:$ TFAE

- $R$ is a semisimple ring.
- Every left $R$ module is QI.
- Every finitely generated left $R$ module is QI.

Is there a similar theorem for PI modules? Since QI implies PI, asking for $R$ to be semisimple, might be to much. Is there any weaker condition on $R$ so that all left $R$ modules are PI? Or is there any situation in which PI and QI are equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Corollary on the second page of ["Quasi-injective and pseudo-injective modules", S.K.Jain & S.Singh, Canad. Math. Bull. 18 (1975), 359-366](http://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CMB-1975-065-3), a module $M$ is quasi-injective if and only if $M\oplus M$ is pseudo-injective. So all modules being pseudo-injective is equivalent to all modules being quasi-injective.